# Docker Build Failing with Given as STDIN as input

Tags: docker, build, command, docker-image

Why Docker image build is getting failed when build with -  ?

**Host Details**

```
 - docker desktop community 2.1.0.5 for Windows 
 - Windows 10
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER "rizwan@gm.com"

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "my_service.py","--input-path= /input.csv", "--output-path=/output.csv"]
```

**Folder Structure**

```
-Root 
 -Application.py 
 -Dockerfile 
 -requirements.txt
```

**COMMAND**

```
 - Failing :  docker build - < Dockerfile
```

> Message: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

```
 - Successful: docker build .
```

Comment: How are you running this? What dir are you running it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```sh
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

it sends *only* the `Dockerfile` to the Docker daemon, but no other files.  When you tell Docker to `COPY` a file into the image, you haven't actually sent it the file.  It's very similar to including everything in your source tree in the `.dockerignore` file.

Typically you'll send Docker the current directory as the context directory instead:

```sh
docker build .  # knows to look for Dockerfile by default
```

Comment: Can we send other context along with dockerfile via - ?

Comment: You could manually [send a compressed tar file to `docker build -`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--) if you really needed to.